# Swift Struct unable to set array elements above 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have following Swift struct:

```
struct MainStruct : Decodable{
var array : [InternalArray]?
}

struct InternalArray : Decodable{
    var firstName : String?
    var lastName : String?
    var Number : Int?
}
```

And this is how I'm using it:

```
var testing: MainStruct? = MainStruct()
testing?.array = []
testing?.array!.append(InternalArray())
testing?.array![0].firstName = "TEST"

testing?.array![1].firstName = "TEST 1" - error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
```

It seems to work fine when I'm setting array element [0] but when I try to set element [1] I get an error. Maybe somebody know what is wrong with my implementation ?

Comment: You have one element but you are trying to access 2nd element.  you need to **append** another **InternalArray** before "Test_1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you only have 1 item (index 0).

Let's unpack this, first we unwrap your option `MainStruct` in the `testing` variable, and unwrap the optional `array`:

```swift
if let unwrappedTestingMainStruct = testing,
   let unwrappedArray = unwrappedTestingMainStruct.array {
    unwrappedArray.count       // = 1
}
```

You then try to access `testing?.array![1]` which would be the second item in the array… which doesn't exist.

If you just had the line:

```
testing?.array![1]
```

you would see the same error